# Handlebars date format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have my handlerbars template with my property

```
{{#each claimsHistory}}
  <td>
    {{lossDate}} 
  </td>
{{/each}}
```

lossDate its my date time, it is rendered like this 2015-08-28T00:00:00

I want to display it as this 2015-08-28 without the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the perfect time to write a handlebars helper! Add this minor modification to your template:

```
{{#each claimsHistory}}
    <td>
        {{formatTime lossDate "MM-DD-YYYY"}} 
    </td>
{{/each}}
```

Then in a `HandlebarsHelpers.js` file that you include in your app:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('formatTime', function (date, format) {
    var mmnt = moment(date);
    return mmnt.format(format);
});
```

`moment` is a popular JavaScript library for manipulating dates.  The helper shown here receives your date and a format string as passed by your template, creates a moment date object, then formats it according to your specified format strings.  For more info on moment, including how to get various formats, go here: http://momentjs.com/docs/.

Of course, you could use vanilla JS date manipulation instead of Moment.js, but how you implement the helper is up to you.

Comment: Please kindly up-vote the answer and "accept" it if this helped you, glad you could make use of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use handlebars helpers. The following will help you achieve your goal.

1. run the following on your terminal to add handlebars helpers to your config.json

   ```
   npm install --save handlebars-helpers
   ```
2. Import the handlebar helper in your app.js using

   ```
   var helpers = require('handlebars-helpers')();
   ```
3. Then in your handlebar template, you'll have

   ```
   {{#each claimsHistory}}
      <td>
         {{moment lossDate format="YYYY-MM-DD"}} 
      </td>
   {{/each}}
   ```

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer did not. Thank you for being so descriptive in your explanation.